# How can I use JavaScript in Razor for google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, razor

I am trying to use a 'foreach' loop to place a series of markers on the map using coordinates from a database. The retrieval of the data is not an issue so for now I'm not bothered about the map showing the correct locations. The issue is that when inside the 'foreach' loop, any code for the marker placement is immediately passed over. Any ideas?

Here is the current code:

```
<script>
    function myMap() {
        var lat = 52.4283381;
        var lng = -1.601519;
        var myLatLng = { lat: 52.428381, lng: -1.601519 };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
        });
    }
</script>

<script>
    @foreach (var mapVars in ViewData.Model)
    {
        <text>
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker
        ({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng (52.428381 , -1.601519),
            map: map,
            title: "" + i,
        });

        </text>
    }
</script>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBfvqLwEOTU3oFoiJOmmloYJFYUA801lF8&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try serialize your ViewData.Model to a javascript object and than loop from there.

Something like this:

```
<script>
    function myMap() {
        var lat = 52.4283381;
        var lng = -1.601519;
        var myLatLng = { lat: 52.428381, lng: -1.601519 };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
        });
    }
</script>

<script>
    window.data = @(Html.Raw(js.Serialize(ViewData.Model)));
    var markers = [];
    for(i = 0; i < window.data.length; i++)
    {
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker
        ({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng (52.428381 , -1.601519),
            map: map,
            title: "" + i,
        }));
    }
</script>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBfvqLwEOTU3oFoiJOmmloYJFYUA801lF8&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I realised that after a good 24 hours of trying to figure it out, all I needed to do was move the marker section inside of the myMap function.... I feel like a bit of an idiot now :/